# Mesh and armature un-synced when canceling pose

Tags: pose-mode

I have a problem in blender that has been driving me insane.  My rig was working correctly and I made some changes in the hierarchy and now it wont work.

In pose mode if I grab and drag a bone it deforms the mesh just as I would expect.  If I want to cancel the action by hitting "escape" the armature snaps back to its original location but the mesh stays where it was when I hit escape.  This is driving me crazy please help.

Thanks.

[image: Original Model]
Here is the original model.

[image: While posing the model before confirming pose by clicking]
This is while I am dragging the pose around before clicking to confirm position.

[image: After canceling the pose by hitting escape.]

This is after canceling the pose by hitting "Esc" without ever clicking to confirm the position.

Please not that if I confirm the position by clicking instead of canceling the pose works fine and the mesh follows the armature as you would expect.

Comment: Please provide screenshots so we can understand the problem easier

Comment: There will be some strange object dependancies, (happens often with drivers) which Blender can't handle. Double check parenting, Constraints and Drivers.